# logic to know the difference between the dateandtime with respect to two fields in a .csv file

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

Need some logic to know the difference between the dateandtime with respect to two fields in a .csv file. i have a csv file which consists of 4 fields([column1,column2,column3,column4]).

For eg:

> [ 'Sequence id', 'Meter', 'Date in meter', 'Connection Status' ]

'Date in Meter' is the time when the connection to server
was established or the meter was disconnected.

The data in csv file looks something like this:

> [ '982009499', '00102B8F', '13-02-2016 23:46', 'Connected' ] [
>   '982014683', '00102B8F', '13-02-2016 23:51', 'Disconnected' ] [
>   '982014971', '00102B8F', '13-02-2016 23:51', 'Connected' ] [
>   '982021347', '00102B8F', '13-02-2016 23:56', 'Disconnected' ] [
>   '982021635', '00102B8F', '13-02-2016 23:57', 'Connected' ] [
>   '982026999', '00102B8F', '14-02-2016 00:02', 'Disconnected' ] [
>   '982027315', '00102B8F', '14-02-2016 00:02', 'Connected' ] [
>   '982033915', '00102B8F', '14-02-2016 00:07', 'Disconnected' ] [
>   '982034263', '00102B8F', '14-02-2016 00:08', 'Connected' ]

**Example**
1. If the meter reported Connected on 10th June 5.30pm and then reported
Disconnected on 13th June 3 am, we will count 10th, 11th, 12th and 13th
June as connected days.

2. If the meter reported Disconnected on 13th June 3 am and indicates
   connected on 15th June 4pm, we will indicate that the meter did not
   communicate with server on 14th June.

For each meter, I need the list of days on which the meter did not com-
municate with the server at all in Javascript.
Please help me. This is my first question on StackOverflow.

I could only code this much.

```
    const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('fast-csv');


var stream = fs.createReadStream("./../ConnectionList(1-50Meters).csv");

var csvStream = csv()
    .on("data", function(data){
         console.log(data);
    })
    .on("end", function(){
         console.log("done");
    });

stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

Comment: If this is all in javascript why do you have sql-server tagged?

Comment: What have you done so far? What are expected results? Do you have any parsing code for that csv? Have you attempted reducing arrays? Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service.The objective here is for others to help you fix your code

Comment: @charlietfl i m newbie to coding.  I have edited question.

Comment: @Brad I have tagged sql-servers, coz  I thought query "partitions over meterId where status is disconnected" can be used